# When does Firebase start pulling data from the database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an web app with Firebase.

Since the target audience varies quite a bit, there are users who may have metered data connection. In order to reduce data used by the app, I would like to find out, which Firebase code is where the database is being pulled from the database (without including of course, the initialization CDN)

Is data pulled when running this?

```
var database = firebase.database().ref();
```

Or is it only pulled when calling

```
database.on("value", function(snapshot){});
```

Thank you in advance and please advice me if I have any misunderstandings as I'm not very experienced :)

Comment: Data is only retrieve from the database once you attach a listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this `var database = firebase.database().ref();` you ceate the reference to a location in the database, example here you created the reference to the root node.

When you execute this `database.on("value", function(snapshot){});` then you are attaching a listener to retrieve the data from the location.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write